# Notice: Undefined index:life in line 117

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have this form, with "input type text" that change their values with javascript code.
They all have names: life, attack, defense, agility.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
   //LINE 117// $life = ($_POST['life']);




    if ($username == "") {
        echo "Por favor, de um nome ao Personagem";
    } elseif (strlen($username) < 3) {
        echo "O nome precisa ter mais que 3 caracteres!";

    } else {
        $reg = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id` FROM personagem WHERE `nome_personagem`='$username'") or die(mysqli_error());
        if (mysqli_num_rows($reg) > 0) {
            echo "Nome já em uso!";
        } else {


            $adc = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO personagem (`nome_personagem`, `agilidade_personagem`, `defesa_personagem`, `ataque_personagem`, `energia_personagem`, `stamina_personagem`, `level_personagem`,`vida_personagem`) VALUES ('$username',10,5,10,100,100,1,100)") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE personagem SET `vida_personagem` = vida_personagem + 1 WHERE `nome_personagem` = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            echo "Personagem Criado com Sucesso!";

        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I run, it says:

> "Notice: Undefined index: life in C:\wamp\www\game\criacao.php on line 117".

Comment: Is there a field with name life in your form

Comment: Is there an input type with name='life' ? if not $_POST['life'] will cause that error

Comment: can i see line no  117?

Comment: Can you pls check this $life = isset($_POST['life']) ? $_POST['life'] : '';

Comment: @sinto yes, It is "<input type="text" id="texto1" value="0" disabled name="life">"

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo line 117 is the 4th line on the code above

Comment: try this : <input type="text" id="texto1" value="0" readonly name="life">

Comment: thanks @sinto problem resolved...

Comment: I think you are trying to use this field only at some instances of your work, so you are made it as disabled. you can try readonly field or a hidden field instead of disabled.

Comment: You are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

your `disabled` inputs doesn't seen, so you must remove `disabled`, so replace this:

```
<input type="text" id="texto1" value="0" disabled name="life">
```

with this:

```
<input type="text" id="texto1" value="0" name="life">
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked... but now, can I disable the input somehow? via javascript?